# google maps v3-- why are these map methods undefined?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm new to the V3 version of the maps API, having used V2 in the past.  As a result, there are some map creation issues I've run into while trying to port our app from V2 to V3.

I'm creating a map like this now, and it seems to work-- I'm returned a map object in the variable `m_oGoogleMap`:

```
    m_oGoogleMap = new google.maps.Map(
    $('Map'), {
        scaleControl: true,
        scaleControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
        },          
        panControl: true,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 8, 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(LAT, LNG)
    });
```

...However, after doing this I cannot call methods such as getBounds() or getProjection() without receiving an undefined error-- I can *see* stubs for those methods while debugging, in the Chrome watch expressions area, but calling them there (or on the page itself) yields an undefined error.  Am I missing how to create and initialize a map in V3?

Other methods on the map object, such as `getDiv()`, work just fine.  So I'm not sure if I have a half-initialized object or what might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation of a map is an asynchronous process, some methods/properties  are not accessible before this process has been finished. Wait for events like `idle` or `tilesloaded` before you access these methods.